# plot each row in a data.frame in a list using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of data.frames and I want to plot each row of each data.frame using ggplot. I'm looking to store these into a variable so then I can plot these in a png in a 20x12 format. Meaning 20 graphs across and 12 down.

Each data.frame in the list would get it's own png file.

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n=240), nrow = 240, ncol = 602))
df_list = list(df,df,df)
plots=list(list(list()))
for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
  for (k in 1:240){
    testdf = as.numeric(t(df[[i]][k,2:ncol(df[[i]])]))
    testtime = seq_along(df[[i]])
    test =((cbind(testtime,testdf)))
    test = as.data.frame(test)
    plots[[k]]=ggplot(aes(`1`,testdf),data=test)+geom_line()
  }
  plots[i]=rbind(plots[[k]],plots)
}
```

The following code gets me the last loop of [i] but it doesnt save the first few loops. Any ideas?

Bonus Points if you know how to plot each [i] into separate png files in a matrix of plots measuring 20x12.

Comment: Why do you make `plots` a list containing a list containing a list? And then only ever access the outermost?

Comment: Also why did you delete the `findpeaks` question the other day? I was about to post an answer. Makes me less interested in putting in work on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I don't like your data - it's all boring straight lines. Let's generate some new data - and since it's all numeric I'll leave it as a matrix instead of converting to data frame:

```
input = replicate(
    n = 3,
    matrix(rnorm(n = 240 * 602), nrow = 240, ncol = 602),
    simplify = F
)
```

Just like in Mark's answer, I'll convert it to long format. Since it's a matrix, we don't need all the data frame editing tools, I'll just `as.vector` the matrix and add on the `index` and `id` columns.

The plotting code is mostly untouched from Mark's answer.

```
plots <- lapply(input, function(mm) { 
    # if you really need to start with data frames, not matrices
    # just put here: mm = as.matrix(mm) 
    df_long = data.frame(id = 1:nrow(mm), index = rep(1:ncol(mm), each = nrow(mm)), value = as.vector(mm))
    ggplot(df_long, aes(x = index, y = value)) +
        geom_line() +
        facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 20) +
        theme(strip.text = element_blank())
})
```

Now, these plots are big! You've got 240 subplots in each list item - I would advise against trying to look at them too much in the GUI. Instead, let's save them as nicely compressed `png`s and view the files.

```
for (i in seq_along(plots)) {
    ggsave(filename = sprintf("myplot%s.png", i),
           plot = plots[[i]],
           height = 30, width = 18)
}
```

I can't upload a plot because it exceeds the maximum filesize - and even then each subplot is pretty small. You may want to up the height and width even more.

This answer is *very close* to Mark's excellent answer - the only differences are the method of reshaping the data and the extra bit on saving.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to tidy your data, you can use this, which will automatically generate the 20x12 layout for each of the data.frames:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n=240), nrow = 240, ncol = 602)) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  gather(index, value, -id) %>%
  mutate(index = parse_number(index))

df_list = list(df,df,df)

catch <- lapply(df_list, function(df){
  ggplot(df
         , aes(x = index
               , y = value)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~id
               , nrow = 20
               , ncol = 12) +
    theme(strip.text = element_blank())
})
```

One of the plots:

[image]

Note that you will want to make thematic changes, particularly if you want to be able to label the individuals, but this at least generates the layout you wanted.

Comment: That is the layout!! If my data frames are already in a list could I loop over them and do what you did to df above in the loop then do the lapply?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. The only issue would arise if the data.frames had some fundamental differences in structure (e.g., missing columns or something).

Comment: I think thet do. One has less columns then the others.

Comment: As long as they are still in the same order, my code should work (it is assigning the index from the column name). Depending on your structure, e.g., if you have different column names than your example, you may need to spend a bit more time thinking through how to construct your data. If you can't get it, you may want to post a separate question asking how to do that.

Comment: Another option would be to do treat them as matrices -- if you skip the `data.frame` conversion for the input (or convert back to a matrix `mm`), then rather than `mutate %>% gather %>% mutate` you could do `df_long = data.frame(id = 1:nrow(mm), index = rep(1:ncol(mm), each = nrow(mm)), value = as.vector(mm))`. Either would fit nicely as part of the `lapply` before the `ggplot`.

Comment: Seems like whenever i try to display the graphs in catch, R just crashes. @gregor, could you explain a little further about your solution?